# how to set max post request size limit for specific url in tomcat?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

The global configuration `maxPostSize` is 20mb, but I want to set it to 1mb only for this url `/api/data/accept`. How to do it appropriately?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring Boot, it would be possible to implement a Filter on that specific url, like in this quick and dirty example:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/data/accept")
@Controller
public class StackOverflowController {

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<String> accept(@RequestBody String body) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Request accepted");
    }

    @PostMapping("/nofilter")
    public ResponseEntity<String> nofilter(@RequestBody String body) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Request accepted");
    }
}

@Component
class OneMegabyteFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        int maxRequestSize = 1_000_000;
        if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
            String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString();
            if (url.endsWith("/api/data/accept") && request.getContentLength() > maxRequestSize) {
                throw new ServletException("Request of size " + request.getContentLength() + " is larger than the allowed size of 1M");
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a log, this can be used as an alternative. I also want to confirm whether a similar configuration is supported in Tomcat's `server.xml` configuration